# binutils/bfd.h wants config.h now?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, binutils

I'm trying to use the BFD library, and so I've installed package `binutils-dev` and have included:

```
#include <bfd.h>
```

and am calling `bfd_openr` and `bfd_close` and so on from my code.

Recently I have upgraded packages and now I get an error from here:

bfd.h:

```
/* PR 14072: Ensure that config.h is included first.  */
#if !defined PACKAGE && !defined PACKAGE_VERSION
#error config.h must be included before this header
#endif
```

...that I should include `config.h` - but I am not using autoconf.

Am I including the wrong header file?  How are you supposed to use binutils-dev?

Here is a demo program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bfd.h>

int main()
{
    bfd_init();

    bfd* file = bfd_openr("a.out", 0);

    if (!file)
        return -1;

    if (bfd_check_format(file, bfd_object))
        printf("object file\n");
    else
        printf("not object file\n");

    bfd_close(file);

    return 0;
}
```

try to compile and run as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get install binutils-dev
$ gcc test.c
In file included from test.c:3:0:
/usr/include/bfd.h:37:2: error: #error config.h must be included before this header
```

Comment: Related: http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14243

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, the most correct way of using the header is to use autotools in your package as well. Some people are simply stubborn and I don't think you can do much about it.

An alternative is to work-around the check, by defining the macros it is using:

```
#define PACKAGE 1
#define PACKAGE_VERSION 1
```

Of course, if you are already defining those, you may as well set them to some reasonable values like:

```
#define PACKAGE "your-program-name"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.2.3"
```

and use them for your program. You'll usually going to use something like that anyway at some point to keep the versions consistent.

This should be enough if you're using a standards-compliant compiler because then the `__STDC__` macro will be declared and everything will go on just fine. Well, as long as the headers you're using won't require more autoconf-generated defines.

For example, if you wanted to use `plugin-api.h`, you'd actually have to handle checking for `stdint.h` and `inttypes.h`...